# How te set a static IP for a Jetson Nano?

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia-jetson-nano

I want to set a static IP for a Jetson Nano in my local network. What I've tried:

-- Changing the DHCP on the router.

-- editing /etc/network/interfaces with the following:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.80
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Both this options doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 6):

It seems the Jetson Nano has an underlying configuration for the network interface of the board.

**1)** edit /etc/default/networking

```
sudo vi /etc/default/networking
```

and set the parameter CONFIGURE_INTERFACES=no

```
# Set to 'no' to skip interfaces configuration on boot
CONFIGURE_INTERFACES=no
```

**2)** Now then the settings in /etc/network/interfaces will work

```
sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.80
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.1.1
```

**3)** Reboot the board

Comment: After doing,  IP become static. But for nano internet is working.  Not  able to install any package.

Answer (score 0):

## TLDR ;

Use `nmcli con mod [id]` and `nmcli con [down up] [id]` as root.

eg:

```bash
nmcli con show 
nmcli con mod "Wired connection 1" \
  ipv4.addresses "192.168.8.70/24" \
  ipv4.gateway "192.168.8.1" \
  ipv4.dns "8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1" \
  ipv4.dns-search "8.8.4.4" \
  ipv4.method "manual"

(nmcli con down id "Wired connection 1" && nmcli con up id "Wired connection 1")& # or reboot device
```

## LR ;

Recent Jetsons nano use linux network-manager to manage network interfaces.
you have to, either use the UI to modify the settings or use cli as below :

1. show network connections with : `nmcli con show`

[nmcli con show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVrLh.png)

2. Edit or Modify the wired network or your preferred interface with

```bash
sudo nmcli con mod "Wired connection 1" \
  ipv4.addresses "192.168.8.70/24" \
  ipv4.gateway "192.168.8.1" \
  ipv4.dns "8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1" \
  ipv4.dns-search "8.8.4.4" \
  ipv4.method "manual"
```

> Edit IPs as suits you and

3. Down/Up connection or reboot your jetson with :

```bash
(nmcli con down id "Wired connection 1" && nmcli con up id "Wired connection 1")&
```

or just `reboot`

after that you'll lose access to it and with another terminal you can ping and access your jetson again.